# OnClick add class to label

Tags: jquery

I am working on a quiz script. I have hidden the radio buttons and wanting to make the label class ( radio button pseudo ) clickable.

I have:

```
<li class="pos-3">
   <input type="radio" value="4" id='radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>' name='<?php echo $result['id'];?>'/>
   <label class="" for="radio1_<?php echo $result['id'];?>"><?php echo $result['answer4'];?></label>
</li>
```

I thought I could achieve this with jQuery like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 if($("input.check").is(":checked")){
$(this).label.addClass("checked");
  }
});
```

But failing miserably.

Any suggestions, the radio click is registering. But the class isnt being added.

There are 4 ( li's ) choices for each question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to have a change handler registered for the radio elements, then you can use .toggleClass() to switch the checked class for the label

```
jQuery(function () {
    $('input[type="radio"]').change(function () {
        $('input[name="' + this.name + '"]').not(this).next().removeClass('checked');
        $(this).next().toggleClass('checked', this.checked)
    })
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/XHgh9/)

Answer (score 0):

You can just add class `checked` to clicked radio button and remove that class from other radio buttons like this:

```
$('input[type="radio"]').change(function () { 
    $('input[type="radio"]').next().removeClass('checked');
    $(this).next().addClass('checked');    
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4AnnT/)**